# sequence of tenses: if ..is.. , .. is

Tags: sequence-of-tenses, if

Why this sentence is legal (from a popular US university book):

> **If** the spring in Fig. 14.2 **is** an ideal one, the total overall range of the motion **is** 2A.

(According to rules it should be:

> **If** the spring in Fig. 14.2 **is** an ideal one, the total overall range of the motion **will be** 2A.)

Please supply a source to the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the future construction, *will be*, is about a prediction for the future, and the present tense is about the present or about general truths.

The sentence about the spring says that if the spring is an ideal one, that fact tells us something about the range of motion *right now*, or as a general fact that is always true.  If we said "then the range of the motion *will be* X", it sounds like a prediction for the future and not a statement about the present or a general truth.

Comment: What about: "If the sound and wind are moving in opposite directions, the speed of the sound wave will be decreased by the speed of the wind."

Comment: @Ben  That is OK too.  This is partly a stylistic choice, and you can read "will be" as referring to "the speed of any sound wave that happens to exist".

Comment: Can you please give a source for the answer?

Comment: The the source for the answer, can be: https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/